# Weakly bounded iff uniformly bounded in $E'$?

Tags: normed-spaces, uniform-distribution

I have a problem:

Suppose that $E$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $E= \{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}\ \text{is continuous and such that}\  f|_{[0, \delta]}=0, \text{with}\ \delta=\delta(f)>0 \}$

with norm:  $\| f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|$

For linear functional consequence $f \mapsto \varphi_n(f)=nf(\frac{1}{n}), \forall n \ge 1$

I'm wondering whether $\{\varphi_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is weakly bounded iff $\{\varphi_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is uniformly bounded in $E'$ (the dual space of $E$).

Comment: What exactly is your question? $\{\varphi_n| n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is weakly bounded but not uniformly (or norm- or strongly) bounded.

Comment: So please edit your question accordingly. Write down your definition of weakly bounded and where you have difficulties to show it.

Comment: If you are thinking about weakly bounded sequences, you are not a beginner in Mathematics. And if you don't know the definition, it is a good idea to seach for it.

Comment: Can you give me a link definition of weakly bounded! Thank you very much! . Vobo.

Comment: I mean that it is $\sigma (E',E)$ - bounded! Can you show me a link?

Answer (score 2):

A subset $B\subset E'$ is *weakly bounded*, iff for each $x\in E$ the set of real numbers
$$
\{ |S(x)|; S\in B \}
$$
is bounded. $B$ is called *uniformly bounded* (or norm-bounded or strongly bounded), iff the bound is uniform for $||x||\leq 1$, i.e. the set 
$$
\{ |S(x)|; S\in B, ||x||\leq 1 \}
$$
is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. In your case, for a fixed $f\in E$, the set
$$
\{ |\varphi_n(f)|; n\in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
is bounded, as only finitely many $\varphi_n(f)$ are non-zero. Now let for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ $g_m\in E$ with $||g_m||\leq 1$ and $g_m(1/m)=1$ (think why such $g_m$ exist). Now conclude why your set in not uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much. Vobo!                             I prove that  $\left \{ \varphi_n \right \}_{n \ge 1}$ is weakly bounded in $E'$ .
We suppose that $f \in E$.
Then $\exists \varepsilon  \in (0,1)$ such that $f=0$ in $\left [ 0,\epsilon  \right ]$.

There exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}^*$ so $\dfrac{1}{n}< \varepsilon , \forall n \ge n_0$
Therefore, $\varphi_n (f)=0,\forall n \ge n_0$

Taking $M:=\sup \left \{\left |\varphi_n (f)  \right |:n=\overline{1,n_0}  \right \} $
$\implies \left |\varphi_n (f)  \right | \le M, \forall n \ge 1$. My solution is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. For the future, you should try to put all this together in your question.

Comment: Firstly, I must say that you are good at maths. I am very grateful for your reply. You had thinked about my problem when i asked. It is respectful.

                                                      The second, I can confirm that my solutions are right. However, I want to see their discussions.
When people comment, reply...I can understand my problem deeply, quickly.

Glad to get acquainted with you. Vobo.

Comment: @canavaro123 However, you are new to this forum and should respect and accept the way it works. You should value the advice and comments you receive (by upvoting and accepting them). In particular, you should edit and retag your question to receive upvotes as well.